# Python/Pygame- How do I make a program so that once they press a key none other ones can be activated?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a quiz game and have run into a bit of a loop hole. I made it so that when the user presses the correct key and the space bar then the points are given t them. But the loop hole is that they can just press everything and then the space bar. so how do i stop this?

```
 keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_w] and (General_knowledge[question_num - 1][5] == "a"):
    test = 1
if keys[pygame.K_d] and (General_knowledge[question_num - 1][5] == "b"):
    test = 1
if keys[pygame.K_s] and (General_knowledge[question_num - 1][5] == "c"):
    test = 1
if keys[pygame.K_a] and (General_knowledge[question_num - 1][5] == "d"):
    test = 1
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    space_bar = 1

if (test == 1) and (space_bar == 1) and (rect_width > 0):
    test = 0
    space_bar = 0
    player_1_score = rect_width / 30
    player_1_score = round(player_1_score, 0)
    print(player_1_score)
```

Comment: Any key + space or 'w/d/s/a' + space ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a simple counter to your code checking if only 1 key is pressed. Try something like this

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
keysPressed = 0;
if keys[pygame.K_w] and (General_knowledge[question_num - 1][5] == "a"):
    test = 1
    keysPressed += 1;
if keys[pygame.K_d] and (General_knowledge[question_num - 1][5] == "b"):
    test = 1
    keysPressed += 1;
if keys[pygame.K_s] and (General_knowledge[question_num - 1][5] == "c"):
    test = 1
    keysPressed += 1;
elif keys[pygame.K_a] and (General_knowledge[question_num - 1][5] == "d"):
    test = 1
    keysPressed += 1;
if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    space_bar = 1

if (test == 1) and (space_bar == 1) and (keysPressed == 1) and (rect_width > 0):
    test = 0
    space_bar = 0
    player_1_score = rect_width / 30
    player_1_score = round(player_1_score, 0)
    print(player_1_score)
```

This way if more than 1 key is pressed then your last `if` statement will fail.